# wordpress Database tables missing after exporting/importing them on phpMyAdmin

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Ok so this is the situation, i have a database that i exported from localhost, there are like 30 or more tables, but when i import them on my live site, there are only 10 tables and worst of all is that the user tables didn't make the cut so i cannot login into the dashboard and continue working, so i wonder what am i missing??? I've followed the steps of this tutorial, which is quoted or shared by so many tutorials on the internet.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/backing-up-your-database/

But i have this situation, nothing goes as it should be, why is this happening and what can i do???
here is the db on the localhost
[image: here is the db on the localhost]

[image: and this is what got imported.]

and this is what got imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i got the solution to my problem, the thing is that I was importing the db compressed in gzip format, and what i needed to do was import without compression, opposite to the tutorial which suggested the use of a compression method. Even the other compression format didn't help either, so importing without a compression method did the job. I got all the tables and all the data imported as it should be and as the tutorial was trying to get. After all, the db was just too small, like 10mb so it has no problem but if your case the db is bigger than 1GB or too big, then maybe this solution is not the correct for you. Thanks to everyone who helped, they indeed share some light about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

On the import screen, There is a checkbox under `Partial Import` stating `Allow the interruption of an import in case the script detects it is close to the PHP timeout limit.`, make sure you have that checkbox unchecked.

Comment: thanks but it didn't work :( What could it be???

Comment: Try dividing the exports into two, and then importing the tables. Or just import the missing tables.

Comment: Are you using the 'Quick' method to export?

Comment: both methods give me this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting into the DB via SSH? If you can do that, you can import using `source path/to/import.sql`.